# Study material for Hardy Fields

Tags: real-analysis

Please suggest me which branch of mathematics, hardy fields are part of and where can I find books to study it extensively.

Comment: I don't really know much about this, but the paper [Asymptotic differential algebra](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~matthias/pdf/hf-survey.pdf) by Aschenbrenner and van den Dries seems like a good introduction (and you can find further references there).

Comment: @HansLundmark: Thanks, looks relevant.